# Connection between html content types and inline/block elements

Tags: html, css

In html, some elements have restrictions on what type of content they allow. An example is the [`<summary>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-summary-element) element, where the content must be either [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) or one element of [heading content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#heading-content-2). This is valid html:

```
<details>
   <summary><span>Foo</span></summary>
   ...
</details>
```

While this is invalid:

```
<details>
   <summary><div>Foo</div></summary>
   ...
</details>
```

Since `<div>` is not phrasing content nor heading content.

But what about this?

```
<details>
   <summary><span style="display: block">Foo</span></summary>
   ...
</details>
```

To my understanding, this should still be valid html, since `<span>` is phrasing content, but due to `display: block`, the `<span>` element will behave the same way as a `<div>` would.

Is there any connection between different types of contents and `inline`/`block` elements, or are they completely different things?

Can I expect browsers to render things correctly when a specific type of content is required, but that content is styled to behave differently than it normally would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no connection between `elements` and semantics, and how you chose to display those elements - the CSS is just styling, and can be made to do whatever. Semantic markup (HTML) is a completely different matter. And there is no correlation between those two, making the `display: block` completely valid.

Comment: Nice :) Are there any elements that have as a requirement that their children are inline/block elements?

Comment: No. There are specific elements that can only be inside other elements, but there is no set rule for how those elements should be displayed. Note that CSS only applies to visual user agents, and HTML doesn't care how you display the content, just how you position the containers in the markup.